# Matching 3 columns in row - if one column is null then exclude it from comparison

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, isnull

```
A   B   C    Equal
1   1   1    Y
2   2   NULL N
```

Hi, I have 3 columns which I need to compare : Columns A,B,C.
If these 3 columns are the same then column 'Equal' = 'Y'

But, if a column is null, then it must be excluded from the comparison, e.g. in the example Row 2 has a null, but the remaining columns are all the same, so the Equal should be yes - because all non-null values are equal

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dedd9/2

I thought I could use isnull(C,A) = A but it does not work. Could anyone help please

```
 declare @t table
 (
 A decimal,B decimal, C decimal
 )

 insert Into @t(A,B,C) values (1,1,1)
 insert Into @t(A,B) values (2,2)

 select A,B,C,'Equal' = case when ISNULL(A,B) = B and ISNULL(B,C) = C and ISNULL(C,A) = A then 'Y' else '' end
 from @t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, that can be easily extended to more than 3 columns:

```
SELECT a, b, c,
       Equal = ( SELECT r = CASE WHEN MIN(v) = MAX(v) THEN 'Y'  -- all non-null values equal
                                 WHEN MIN(v) < MAX(v) THEN 'N'  -- at least 2 non equal 
                                 ELSE 'Y'                       -- all nulls
                            END 
                 FROM (VALUES (a), (b), (c)) AS x (v)
               ) 
FROM t ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f11ba/2)**.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want all `NULL`s to count as equal, I think this will work. But I haven't thoroughly tested it, or even thought about it for very long...

```
 select A,B,C,'Equal' = 
    case when COALESCE(A,B,C,0) = COALESCE(B,C,A,0)
          and COALESCE(B,C,A,0) = COALESCE(C,A,B,0)
     then 'Y' else '' end
 from @t
```

`COALESCE` will pick the first non-`NULL` value from its arguments, so when testing `A` against `B` and then `B` against `C`, in each case we look 'forward' for a non-`NULL` value, with a fallback for when they're all `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there with your query. However, your query fails, when validating isnull(A,B) = B, when B is null, since NULL **does not** equal NULL in sql.

try this:

```
 declare @t table
 (
 A decimal,B decimal, C decimal
 )

 insert Into @t(A,B,C) values (1,1,1)
 insert Into @t(A,B) values (2,2)
 insert Into @t(A,C) values (2,2)
 insert Into @t(A,C) values (2,3)
 insert Into @t(A,B,C) values (2,2,3)


select 
  A
, B
, C
, 'Equal' = case when ISNULL(A,B) = ISNULL(B, A)
                  and ISNULL(B,C) = ISNULL(C, B)
                  and ISNULL(C,A) = ISNULL(A, C)
            then 'Y' else '' end
 from @t
```